# Python - TypeError: unbound method twitch_connect() must be called with Twitch instance

Tags: python

For a couple of hours now, I have been messing with code to make a Twitch Plays stream on Twitch. I just got to the end, and tried to run it in Liclipse, but it says...

> TypeError: unbound method twitch_connect() must be called with Twitch instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Here is the full code:

```
#Define the imports
import twitch
import keypresser
import keyholder
t = twitch.Twitch
k = keypresser.Keypresser
seconds = 2

#Enter your twitch username and oauth-key below, and the app connects to twitch with the details.
#Your oauth-key can be generated at http://twitchapps.com/tmi/
username = "notgoingtoshow";
key = "notgoingtoshow";
t.twitch_connect(username, key)

#The main loop
while True:
    #Check for new mesasages
    new_messages = t.twitch_recieve_messages();

    if not new_messages:
        #No new messages...
        continue
    else:
        for message in new_messages:
            #Wuhu we got a message. Let's extract some details from it
            msg = message['message'].lower()
            username = message['username'].lower()
            print(username + ": " + msg);

            #This is where you change the keys that shall be pressed and listened to.
            #The code below will simulate the key q if "q" is typed into twitch by someone
            #.. the same thing with "w"
            #Change this to make Twitch fit to your game!
            if msg == "start": k.key_press("enter");
            if msg == "b": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
            if msg == "a": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
            if msg == "up": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
            if msg == "down": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
            if msg == "left": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
            if msg == "right": keyholder.holdForSeconds(key, seconds);
```

Is there any fix to this?

Comment: `t = twitch.Twitch` so `t` is the class? do you mean to instantiate it? `t = twitch.Twitch` **`()`**

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `twitch_connect` from the class object not an instance, but the `twitch_connect` method takes `self` (or an instance of the class) as first argument:

```
t = twitch.Twitch
```

You should instantiate you class using `()`:

```
t = twitch.Twitch()
t.twitch_connect(username, key)
```

Only static and class methods can be called from the class itself. But that is another different story.